# Why my objects are showing in this color?

Tags: 3d

I am new to 3D software and have just started with Cinema 4d. When I add an object it shows on a weird color different from the one I see in tutos.

The tutorial videos I have seen create objects where the faces can be see in white. What am I doing wrong?

Image relating to the problem:[image]

While the tutorial shows this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image from the tutorial has a white material applied to it. You can see it in the object manager, it’s the white sphere. By default, C4D uses a grey material.  To do the same, create a new material in the material manager (the empty area under the timeline) by using the "Create" menu ->New Material or ->New PBR Material, depending on your preference.  Both of those are white by default.  Then, drag the newly created material to your object, either by dragging to the object in the viewport, or in the object manager.